# upload data to specific google drive account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to Upload data (image or video)  to specific google drive.
I want users of my app to sign in to their google account then select specific file from Documents and then upload file to Specific Google Drive **(Not on Users Google Drive)**

**What Have I Done so Far?**

Till now, my app is working fine. user logged in using google account and selects file. But this file goes to their Google Drive.
I have searched for Upload data to other google drive using google drive api but not find anything useful.

**What I Want to Achieve?**

I want when user upload data (Video) it goes to Specific Google Drive. I have App_Key of Google Drive on which i want to upload data.

My code for Login and Upload data is attached.

Thank you.

**Login Code**

```
GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();
startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);

private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions
              .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
              .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
              .build();
          return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    }
```

**Upload File using this:**

```
    final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder();
    final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = mDriveResourceClient.createContents();
    Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, createContentsTask)
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<DriveFile> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                    DriveFolder parent = rootFolderTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                    File file = new File(uri.toString());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                        baos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
                    }
                    OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());

                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle("MyVideo.mp4") // Provide you video name here
                            .setMimeType("video/mp4") // Provide you video type here
                            .build();

                    return mDriveResourceClient.createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                    new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it to another google drive account I think what you can use is [Google's Team Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-teamdrives)

*Team Drives is a shared space where teams can easily store, search, and access their files anywhere, from any device.*
Then you can add user who is currently signed in as part of your team. Then they can share and upload to that specific team drive.

I hope it helps.

Comment: No. i dont want this. in Team Drives the Google Drive Account Holder have to add the members in Team first. 
What i want is:
Add the Google Drive Account Holder's account into my App and anyone logged in using their account can upload data to that account,

Comment: Something you can call Shared Folder.
So, Everyone can have access to that folder and Everyone can directly upload data to that folder. Without Account Holders permission.